# Loading fonts in Ruby on Rails project taking too much time

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, fonts

I am in a Rails project and I am using two fonts which are in the `/assets/fonts` folder.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: FuturaStd-Light;
  src: url("/assets/fonts/FuturaStd-Light.otf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: HelveticaNeue;
  src: url("/assets/fonts//HelveticaNeue.dfont");
}
```

The fonts are very big files (especially the second one) and it is taking forever to load them. And in every page the text appears after everything else.

Is there a better way to load the fonts? Is there a way to cache them? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@font-face is a wonderful technique, but large font files will definitely slow down your site. There are many techniques you can use to combat this:

- use a font-hosting service like [google fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/) or [typekit](http://typekit.com/)
- host your font files on a CDN
- optimize your font files using a service like [fontsquirrel](http://fontsquirrel.com/)

One thing in particular to watch out for is that IE will block the rendering of the entire page if there's a `SCRIPT` element before your stylesheet. So make sure that all your stylesheet links are above any javascript files you're loading.

Further reading:

- [Web Font Performance: Weighing @font-face Options and Alternatives](http://www.artzstudio.com/2012/02/web-font-performance-weighing-fontface-options-and-alternatives/)
- [@font-face and performance](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/)
- [fighting the FOUT](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Scott, @font-face may slow down your site and so depending on your goals you may want to go with google fonts, typekit, or another online font provider.  For a project I'm currently working on I chose google fonts. All you have to do is add the snippet google web fonts to your to your applications.html.erb:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And then add it to your css file:

```
h1 {
  font-family: "PT Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```